# Representations of $GL_n$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and comsider a homomorphism $f\colon \mathsf{SL}_n(k)\longrightarrow k^\times$. I know that every such homomorphism can be extended to all of $\mathsf{GL}_n(k)$ if $k=\mathbb{C}$. What about $k$ alg. closed?

Comment: Possibly the question is not the one you meant to ask, in light of the point raised by @D_S... ?

Comment: I wanted just know more about the representations of $\mathsf{SL}_n$, therefore my problem is completely solved by his answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$ is its own derived group, so any such homomorphism is trivial.